# Absolute reference Javascript var in Cyclical Binds

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have created the below function to bind to all the classes of type `.wrapper` in my page. The problem I have is that when I trigger any of these events, the var 'this' no longer points to the binding it's particular loop, but rather the 'this' that was used in the final iteration of the looping bind. This seems like a mistake in my understanding of how var's are stored at binding, rather than as a value, they are stored as pointers. Can anyone help to show me how I can make these binds remain relevant to their objects.

```
var pullUpEl, pullUpOffset, generatedCount = 0, index = 0, wrappers = [];

$('.wrapper').each(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('tooltip')) {
        pullUpEl = $(this)[0].getElementsByTagName("div")[0].getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
        pullUpOffset = pullUpEl.offsetHeight;
                    
        wrappers[index] = new iScroll($(this).attr('id'), {
            useTransition: true,
            fadeScrollbar: true,
            hideScrollbar: false,
            hScrollbar: false,
            //snap: 'li',
            onRefresh: function () {
                if (pullUpEl.className.match('loading')) {
                    pullUpEl.className = '';
                    pullUpEl.querySelector('.pullUpLabel').innerHTML = 'Pull up to load more...';
                }
            },
            onScrollMove: function () {
                if (this.y < (this.maxScrollY - 5) && !pullUpEl.className.match('flip')) {
                    pullUpEl.className = 'flip';
                    pullUpEl.querySelector('.pullUpLabel').innerHTML = 'Release to refresh...';
                    this.maxScrollY = this.maxScrollY;
                } else if (this.y > (this.maxScrollY + 5) && pullUpEl.className.match('flip')) {
                    pullUpEl.className = '';
                    pullUpEl.querySelector('.pullUpLabel').innerHTML = 'Pull up to load more...';
                    this.maxScrollY = pullUpOffset;
                }
            },
            onScrollEnd: function () {
                if (pullUpEl.className.match('flip')) {
                    pullUpEl.className = 'loading';
                    pullUpEl.querySelector('.pullUpLabel').innerHTML = 'Loading...';
                    pullUpAction(this, pullUpEl.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0]);
                }
            }
        });
    } else {
        wrappers[index] = new iScroll($(this).attr('id'));
    }
    index++;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a problem with `this`, it's a problem with `pullUpEl`. You made this global, so it's final value is the last element in the `.each()` block. When your `onRefresh`, `onScrollMove`, etc. functions are ran, they are not ran in the context where `pullUpEl` is actually changing. So, essentially, no matter which element triggers this, all the changes are run on the last element of the loop every time.

Comment: Thanks Chris. Such a silly oversight on my part! If you feel upto the challange I have one other very difficult problem outstanding ;) I would be super grateful if you could take a peek! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10878726/mouseenter-mouseleave-triggering-prematurely-with-custom-tiered-menu-using-qtip2             Thanks AGAIN! Cheers Devin

Answer (score 0):

Informally, `this` evaluates to the context (implicit parameter) of the first lexically enclosing `function`. You can capture it though:

```
function f() {
    var self = this;
    function g() {
        // here "self" evaluates to the context of f, "this" evaluates to the one of g
    }
}
```

To run in the browser console, try:

```
function f() {
    var self = this;
    return function g() {
        console.log(String(self));
        console.log(String(this));
    }
}

f.apply(1).apply(2)
```

For the gory details, see [ECMA 262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf), 11.1.1:

> The `this` keyword evaluates to the value of the `ThisBinding` of the
>   current execution context.

The standard specifies that `ThisBinding` changes only when entering function code or entering `eval` code.

Comment: To the upvoter: this is answer is 95% wrong, please don't upvote

Comment: Really? Feel free to educate me.

Comment: Well for starters you could try your code out and see that your assumptions in the comment are wrong

Comment: The correct name for "implicit parameter" is "context". And it does not refer to the function object, but its context.

Comment: @Bergi by looking at a function, you can never tell what `this` is because that's not how it works. It depends entirely on how you call the function. The terms don't even matter because saying "`this` always..." is instantly wrong.

Comment: @Esailija: Yes, correct, the context can even be the function itself. I didn't mean "never refers to"...

Comment: @Bergi context and "the value of `this` inside a function" mean the same thing, so saying *`this` always refers to the context* is like saying *`this` always refers to the value of `this`* :X

Comment: I sure can remove "always." I maintain that my comment is correct and helpful, if you are willing to be forgiving for my imprecise use of terminology.